# How to make body content overflow horizontally only?

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I am trying to have a page overflow horizontally and not vertically, so if the content does not fit in the page window, i would like it to be scrollable only via the overflow-x bar, thus keeping the page a fixed height. The idea is to make it 'grow' horizontally - so to the right.
Could this be done with CSS ideally?

Any help will be appreciated! :)

Thanks and take care,
Sincerely,
Piotr.

Comment: overflow-x : visible comes into mind for this....!!

Answer (score 6):

Here's the solution :). This does not require to set a fixed width, but you still have to control the height of your content. And in production you'll most probably want to add inner containers, and add some tweaks to make it work in IE.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AWq39/7/.

```
<body>
    <div class="page-container">...</div>
    <div class="page-container">...</div>
    <div class="page-container">...</div>
</body>

html, body{
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0;
}
.page-container{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    padding: 0 2em;
    font-size: 14px;
    white-space: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make it grow automatically. Instead of a set width i.e. `width: 6000px;` you can use `width: max-content;` and it will scale automatically to fit horizontally with your content.

```
height:100%;
width: max-content;
overflow-y:hidden; #optional if you want to lock down height.
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't automatically grow horizontally but you can easily set it to scroll horizontally if your content demands. You need to set fixed widths to accommodate for the content. Example, fixed `height:100%;`, fixed `width:6000px;` and an `overflow-y:hidden; overflow-x:scroll;` which unfortunately isn't fully compatible with all browsers.

Comment: so there is absolutely no way to have dynamically growing width of the page as opposed to its height?

Comment: It depends on the content, and it depends on the DOM elements you use. Floated elements will not continue to float in a line unless the parent container has a fixed width which accommodates them. You can achieve this with JavaScript by calculating widths of the floated elements, adding them up, and setting the container width to accommodate.

Comment: i think i may just do that... but there isn't any way for the child elements to dynamically 'stretch' the width of their container, like they do the height, without any js intervention?

Comment: Not out of the confines of the window. I imagine you're not wanting a 6000px wide, 2 line paragraph, right? You want blocks of content one after another hidden off screen to the right but they still read top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

```
height:100%;
width:auto;
overflow:hidden
```

That should do the trick. Just make sure your content does not get higher than the page width or it will be clipped. You could fix that with javascript, creating a new column when the content length exceeds the height.

OK, width:auto doesn't work with floating elements inside... if using javascript (jquery) that can be fixed too.
demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3dC5/